# php How to concatenate 2 arrays in one array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, associative-array

I have the following array with 2 elements:

```
$attribute_metric = array(2) 
{
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "white"
    [1]=>
    string(6) " Black"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "S"
    [1]=>
    string(2) " L"
    [2]=>
    string(2) " M"
  }
}
```

and I want to concatenate its elements in a way where I get one array that has 6 elements

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "white, S"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "white, L"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "white, M"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "Black, S"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "Black, L"
  [5]=>
  string(8) "Black, M"
 }
```

I have tried the following but it's not working:

```
$size = 1;
foreach ($attribute_metric as $key => $value) {
    $size = $size * sizeof($value);
}
foreach ($attribute_metric as $key => $value) {
    if($key > 0){
        foreach ($attribute_metric[0] as $subkey => $subvalue) {
            array_push($subvalue,$value);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Implementation of snippet of accepted answer at dupe target: https://3v4l.org/GEgJtI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$list = array(array('white','Black'), array('S','L','M'));
$result = array();
foreach ($list[0] as $k) {
    foreach ($list[1] as $t) {
        $result[] = $k.','.$t;
    }
}
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.. I will choose it as the best answer since my arrays can't be always colours and size ..so this way makes it more dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

```
$array1= $attribute_metric[0]; //['white','black']
$array2= $attribute_metric[1]; // ['S', 'L', 'M']
$resultArray = [];  


foreach ($array1 as $color){
    foreach ($array2 as $size){
        $resultArray[] = $color . ', ' . $size;
    }
}

print_r($resultArray);
```

results

```
Array
(
    [0] => white, S
    [1] => white, L
    [2] => white, M
    [3] => black, S
    [4] => black, L
    [5] => black, M
)
```

Comment: `$resultArray[] = $color . ', ' . $size;` -> mind the "comma".

Answer (score 2):

If the original arrays are not too large then using nested loops would allow you to generate the desired output.

```
$colours=array('white','black');
$sizes=array('s','m','l');

$out=array();
foreach( $colours as $colour ){
    foreach( $sizes as $size ){
        $out[]=$colour.', '.$size;
    }
}
print_r( $out );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness sake and if you want to do it just using array functions:

```
$output = array_reduce(array_map(function($a) use($attribute_metric) {
            return array_map(function($b) use($a) { return $a . ', ' . $b; }, $attribute_metric[1]);
}, $attribute_metric[0]), 'array_merge', []);
```